# solving if apple adds class in private framework the same name as an existing class in obj-c / NSKeyedUnarchiver

Tags: ios, objective-c

Just wanted to put a solution somewhere as took a bit to figure out what happens when apple add a new private framework with a class name that is the same as yours -- this happened to us with iOS 1.45 and caused issues NSKeyedUnarchiver and objective-c will use the private frame class before your class

Answer (score 0):

## INSTANCE SOLUTION

```
    NSData *archive = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:archive];
    [unarchiver setRequiresSecureCoding:NO];
    [unarchiver setClass:[YourClass class] forClassName:@"YourClass"];
    Object* decodedObject = [unarchiver decodeObjectOfClass:[YourClass class] forKey:NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey];
    [unarchiver finishDecoding];
```

## Ensure your NSCodable supports secure coding

```
@property (class, readonly) BOOL supportsSecureCoding;


+ (BOOL)supportsSecureCoding {
    return NO;
}
```